# Как выводить каждую секунду числа в интервале введёном пользователем на js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Напишите функцию, которая принимает два числа. Каждую секунду необходимо выводить числа в интервале от первого до второго принятого числа. Используйте setInterval.

Например, пользователь ввёл числа 5 и 15. Каждую секунду в консоль должно печататься число, начиная с 5 и заканчивая 15 (всего 11 чисел: 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код выводит числа от 1 до 10 сразу, а надо по очереди каждую секунду

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Покажите код, в котором возникли сложности

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Comment: Код необходимо добавлять не картинкой, а текстом. Картинка не индексируется и читать данные с картинки крайне сложно, а так же не возмно скопировать данные для воспроизведения

Comment: Понял, буду знать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем варианте, цикл `while` запускал все **setInterval** сразу.

Надо объявить один интервал и когда условия прекращения вывода будут выполнены, остановить его работу с помощью **clearInterval**, т.к. после запуска интервала, он будет работать бесконечно(до завершения скрипта или до перезагрузки браузера, если скрипт запущен в браузере)

```js
function intUser(a,b) {
  let i = setInterval(() => {
    console.log(a++);
    if (a > b) clearInterval(i);
  }, 1000)
}

intUser(5, 10);
```